# Tree implementation using Lists of children in C++

Tags: c++, tree

Hey here is what I have so far. I am supposed to make a tree ADT implementation as lists of children. I am not sure whether what I'm doing is correct or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int maxcells = 1000;
const int maxnodes = 1000;

template<class T> class LoCTree{

public:

    LoCTree();
    ~LoCTree();
    int firstNodeSpot();
    int firstCellSpot();
    int lastN(int head);
    int nodePos(int head, int n);
    int getNodePosition(int node);
    int getCellPosition(int header);
    T label(int node);
    int create0(T label);
    int create1(T label, int tree1);
    int create2(T label, int tree1, int tree2);
    int create3(T label, int tree1, int tree2, int tree3);
    int leftmostChild(int node);
    int rightSibling(int node);
    int parent(int node);
    int root(int node);
    void makenull();
    void print(int head);
    void preorder(int node);

    private:
    struct node{

        T label;
        int header;
        int position;

        node(){
            label = T();
            header = -1;
            position = -1;
        }

    };
    node nodespace[maxnodes];

    struct cell{
        int node;
        int next;
    };
    cell cellspace[maxcells];
};

template<class T> LoCTree<T>::LoCTree(){
    for(int a=0;a<maxcells;a++){
        cellspace[a].node = -1;
        cellspace[a].next = -1;
    }
    for(int b=0; b< maxnodes;b++){
        nodespace[b].label = T();
        nodespace[b].header = -1;
    }
}
template<class T> LoCTree<T>::~LoCTree(){

}
template<class T> int LoCTree<T>::firstNodeSpot(){
    for(int a=0; a<maxnodes; a++){
        if(nodespace[a].header==-1){
            return a;
        }
    }
        return -1;
}
template<class T> int LoCTree<T>::firstCellSpot(){
    for(int a=0; a<maxcells; a++){
        if(cellspace[a].node==-1){
            return a;
        }
    }
        return -1;
}

template<class T> int LoCTree<T>::create0(T label){
    int nodespot = firstNodeSpot();
    if(nodespot != -1){
        nodespace[nodespot].label = label;
        nodespace[nodespot].position = 0;
        return nodespot;
    }
    return -1;
}
template<class T> int LoCTree<T>::create1(T label, int tree1){
    int nodespot = create0(label);
    if(nodespot != -1){
        int cellspot = firstCellSpot();
        nodespace[nodespot].header = cellspot;
        cellspace[cellspot].node = nodespot;
        nodespace[tree1].position = nodespot;
        cellspace[cellspot].node = tree1;
        return nodespot;
    }
    return -1;
}
template<class T> int LoCTree<T>::create2(T label, int tree1, int tree2){
    int anode = create1(label,tree1);
    if(anode != -1){
        cellspace[nodespace[anode].header].next = firstNodeSpot();
        nodespace[tree2].position = anode;
        cellspace[firstNodeSpot()].node = tree2;
        return anode;
    }
    return -1;
}

template<class T> void LoCTree<T>::print(int head){
    //cout << head;

    int nodespot = head;
    int cellspot = -1;
    int tmp = -1;
    while(nodespace[nodespot].header!=-1){
        cout << nodespace[nodespot].label;
        cellspot = nodespace[nodespot].header;
        tmp = cellspace[cellspot].next;
        if(tmp == -1){
            int tmp1 = nodespace[nodespot].header;
            nodespot = cellspace[cellspot].node;
            if(nodespot == tmp1){
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            nodespot = cellspace[cellspot].next;
        }
    }
    cout << nodespace[nodespot].label;

    //cout << nodespace[3].label;
    //cout << nodespace[getNodePosition(cellspace[getCellPosition(0)].node)].label << endl;
    //cout << nodespace[getNodePosition(cellspace[getCellPosition(0)].node)].label << endl;
        /*
        while(node!=-1){
            cout << nodespace[node].label;
            node = cellspace[nodespace[node].header].next;
        }
    }*/
}
```

Comment: I've fixed your formatting for you - for future reference, select your code and hit the 101010 button to format it readably.

Comment: thank you. Its the first time i'm using this site

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you are not just using linked lists for the children?  For example, here is a really basic example in pseudocode:

```
template<class T>
class Treenode
{
public:
   Treenode* children;
   T data;

   Treenode(T _data) {
      children = 0;
      data = _data;
   }

   addChild(Treenode* t) {
      t->next = children;
      children = t;
   }

   addNewChild(T _data)
   {
      addChild(new Treenode(_data));
   }

   Treenode* getNthChild(int n) {
      int i = 0;
      for (Treenode* t = children, int i = 0 ; t != 0 ; t = t->next, i++ ) {
         if (i == n) return t;
      }
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes unfortunately the task explicitly asks to use the structure i have used and not linked lists for the children. I'm honestly pretty confused

Comment: Hm.  Ok well you can certainly simplify your code by just having one array rather than two.  I don't think there's any reason you have to have a separate array for nodespace and cell space.  Each node has a corresponding cell, correct?  And there's a one-to-one relationship between node and cells?  So if that's the case you can just put everything into one struct and have a single array of those.

Comment: im totally stuck and almost giving up. Is there any solution out there already? thanks

Comment: hope you didn't give up.  There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your solution, you just have to work at it and debug.  Put in print statements so you know what is going on.